# Customize some core Bolts and Spouts in StormCrawler based artifact

Tags: stormcrawler

I have created an artifact based on the available archetype for StormCrawler on http://stormcrawler.net/. According to the customer requirements, we need to modify some codes in the StormCrawler SDK. So We added the decompiled version of some SDK classes to our project. But we encountered some compilation problems about package and class visibility of some **com.digitalpebble.*** namespace. Because we are customizing the SDK codes in our distinct namespace; for example **com.mycompoany**. What is the true approach for customizing some core functionality of StormCrawler project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get copy the source code of whichever bolt you want to customise from GitHub and put it in the src directory of the project generated from the archetype. Build it with *mvn clean package*, change the class names in the Flux file if necessary and run it as usual.